# "Default Value or Binding" containing a double quoatation

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to modify a column to have the default value of

```js
{"permission": false}
```

I'm receiving a validation error which I expected, however I cant find the correct syntax, I have tried all of the sensible escape sequences I can imagine.

[image]

Any idea's much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the whole value in single quotes.

`'{"permission": false}'`

Comment: Thanks wheatin, I cant believe that wasn't one of the combinations I tried

Answer (score 0):

Nvarchar(max) does not allow you to set a default value.

Do you really need a column this size?

The maximum defined size for nvarchar is 4000 - nvarchar(4000) which will accept N'{"permission": false}' as a default value.

The same is also true for varchar except that the maximum defined size is 8000

in which case your default value would be '{"permission": false}'

Hope this helps